# Find a user using Telephone number property using Directory searcher (or) User principal?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am trying to find user details in active directory by using telephone number registered. I have formed the search filter but doesn't return the user instead returns null always. Where Am i wrong? Is it could be done using User principal? Help me.

The code that I have tried so far:

```
 DirectoryEntry _entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://Address",ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADDomainUserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADDomainPassword"]);

                DirectorySearcher _searcher = new DirectorySearcher(_entry);
                _searcher.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=group)(objectCategory =person)(telephoneNumber = " + phoneNumber + "))");

                SearchResult item = _searcher.FindOne();

                var tn = item.Properties["telephonenumber"][0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your requirement, I think your search filter should be something like this:

```
"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(telephoneNumber=" + phoneNumber + "))"
```

Also, you should be very clear with the format of the telephoneNumber which you will be passing into the filter as it has to match while searching.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just to be clear, the problem in the original query is `(objectClass=group)`, which would find groups, not users.

Comment: The problem I had faced is `String.Format()` after removing and using above format working fine!. Thanks @akg179.